# Could I go to jail for using someone else's credit card?

Tags: united-states, theft

So I'm 13(thirteen) and I was on amazon and I looked up random card numbers not expecting it to work and to be used as a prank on my friends. It turns out, the number I was given was active and had money on it, and I can't undo my purchase.
I'm very scared that I'm going to go to jail and have to pay for my purchase.
I have no money and my parents are broke and we are on the verge of living on the streets and I'm so scared. Please Help.

Comment: In theory, yes: what you did is credit-card fraud.  In practice, they usually don't bother prosecuting for small fraudulent purchases.

Answer (score 6):

If you were an adult, the risk would be a lot higher. You can get away with things when you are 13. And since you are not an adult, the purchase contract is voidable so your parents *can* void your purchase.

Don't do this ever again. It's not a "prank". You say you have no money and your parents have no money. The money on that card could be the last bit of money that the card owner had. Worst case someone has become homeless, had a bit of money in his card account, and you took the last of their savings. Does that make you feel bad? It should.